# Data pre-processing with Leap Motion

Tags: leap-motion

Does the Leap Motion device perform any filtering on the measurements it takes before constructing a frame? In other words, are extreme values in the Leap's measurements smoothed out before being presented to the developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Leap Motion software does quite a bit between taking a snapshot of the sensors' field of view and constructing the eventual Frame object presented by the API. Among other things, this includes a certain amount of filtering. The methods and amount of filtering are an implementation detail that are subject to change as we are always working on improving the software. For example, in the next major version of the software (now in beta), an internal skeletal model of the human hand is fit to the observed data, which is quite a different method than is used in the current version.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any article explaining how the filtering is done? I'm interested in the algorithm they use to do it.